# Start pig grunt shell and execute commands using c#

Tags: apache-pig, interactive-shell

I am working on achieving the execution of commands on pig grunt shell using c#. I am able to start the grunt shell through c# program using the following code:

```
proc = new Process {StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = PIG_BIN + "\\pig.cmd",                
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardError = true ,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    }
                };
```

I read the output and error through the following methods and events:

```
     proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
  proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
  proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_ErrorDataReceived;
  proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

But, I am unable to read the output line from grunt shell. But, only the lines before the "grunt>" is alone read.

I pass arguments to grunt shell through the following command,

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("dump a;");
```

I am not able to pass the arguments to grunt shell too. A java process is started when we start the grunt shell. If I end the java.exe in command prompt, "OutputDataReceived " event is hit and "grunt>" is obtained.

I hope that grunt is running as a java process and hence we are not able to pass and receive arguments to and from it. Is there any way to achieve it??